# Type of rest parameters of a Function type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get the type of the arguments of a function type? For instance:

```
type MyFn = (a: number, b: string): boolean;
const fnInstance: MyFn = (...args) => true; // args are any[] here, causing `noImplicitAny` flag to issue an error
```

Is there a way to get what type `...args` should be, based on the `MyFn` type? Should be `[number, string]`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, a rest parameter must be of type array.

To avoid the problem of `nomImplicitAny`, you just define the rest argument as `any[]`.

This is not a problem, because TypeScript won't care about the definition of `fnInstance` when you use it, just about the type you specified, so, when invokint it, it'll expect two arguments, a `number` an a `string`:

```
const fnInstance: MyFn = (...args: any[]) => true;

fnInstance(3, "hello"); // right
fnInstance(3, 4); // error
```

in your const definition, you are making the following type casts:

```
(...args: any[]) => boolean --> MyFn
```

So, in the end you've got `MyFn` in the end. As long as the inferred type of the definition of the function is assignable to `MyFn`, there won't be any problem. In this case, it is assignable.

You'd get an error, however, if you tried this:

```
const fnInstance: MyFn = (...args: any[]) => 7;
```